# Saving gzip file from Async HTTP request with Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, gzip, python-asyncio

I'm trying to save a bunch of gzip files from an API response in async. Basically, I'm getting an array with different URI's and I have to append these to a base URL in order to download the .gz file. In the .gz files is a text file formatted as JSON. I already have code working in a synchronous way, but I would like to try async to minimize the runtime. I have tried an async way below and this does give me .gz files, but when I try to extract these nothing is in them. Any help or ideas are much appreciated!

This is the synchronous code:

```
from get_countryfile import uri_response, request_url
import requests
import os
import pathlib

access_token = get_access_token()

print(access_token)
for uri in uri_response:
    request_url = request_url + uri['uri'] + '?access_token=' + access_token
    request = requests.get(request_url)
    with open('filename' + uri['description'] + '.json.gzip', 'wb') as myfile:
        myfile.write(request._content)
```

and this is the async code I have so far:

```
from get_access_token import get_access_token
from get_countryfile import uri_response, request_url
import aiohttp
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import gzip

async def get_file():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        for uri in uri_response:
            file_url = request_url + uri['uri']+'?access_token='+ get_access_token()
            async with session.get(file_url) as resp:
                with open('filename' + uri['description'] + '.json.gzip', 'w') as myfile:
                    print(resp.read())
                    
asyncio.run(get_file())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing an await. The `resp.read()` method is async. To run async functions in other functions we need to use `await <function>`.

```py
from get_access_token import get_access_token
from get_countryfile import uri_response, request_url
import aiohttp
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import gzip

async def get_file():

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:

        for uri in uri_response:
            file_url = request_url + uri['uri']+'?access_token='+ get_access_token()
            async with session.get(file_url) as resp:
                with open('filename' + uri['description'] + '.json.gzip', 'w') as myfile:
                    print(await resp.read())
                    
asyncio.run(get_file())
```

Comment: @Niels if it worked for you, please approve my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the asynchronous for loop, it is a built in construct in newer Python 3 versions.

See here: https://quentin.pradet.me/blog/using-asynchronous-for-loops-in-python.html